# Why does a for loop not require the iterator to be mutable?

Tags: rust, immutability

I do not understand the mutability of Rust iterators. To try to figure it out, I have the following:

```
struct Fibonacci {
    curr: u32,
    next: u32,
}

impl Iterator for Fibonacci {
    type Item = u32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<u32> {
        let new_next = self.curr + self.next;
        self.curr = self.next;
        self.next = new_next;
        Some(self.curr)
    }
}

fn fibonacci() -> Fibonacci {
    Fibonacci { curr: 1, next: 1 }
}

fn main() {
    let f: Fibonacci = fibonacci();
    for i in f.take(5) {
        println!("> {}", i);
    }
}
```

Very simply, I have a custom iterator that I return using `fibonacci`. Now, when I create this, the `f` variable is immutable. What happens in the `for` loop that makes this work? Didn't the for loop just use `f` mutably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Didn't the for loop just use `f` mutably?

No. [`take` returns a *new* iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take). But even then, [`for` is syntactic sugar](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.18.0/std/iter/index.html#for-loops-and-intoiterator). Your code gets transformed into

```
let f: Fibonacci = fibonacci();

{
    let result = match IntoIterator::into_iter(f.take(5)) {
        mut iter => {
            loop {
                match iter.next() {
                    Some(i) => {
                        println!("{}", i);
                    }
                    None => break,
                }
            }
        }
    };
    result
}
```

Due to `IntoIterator`, we never have to mutate `f` or `f.take(5)`, but only the result of `into_iter`.